# Can't authorize with google plus API

Tags: python, authorization, google-plus, google-api-python-client

I am trying to authorize my app using google plus. However, everything I've tried always gives me a 404 when I use the people service and attempt to get 'me', except when I log in with the user who created the Google+ API app. It doesn't make any sense to my why that would be the case.

```
from httplib2 import Http
from apiclient.discovery import build
credential = gp_client.step2_exchange(request.REQUEST)
http = Http()
http = credential.authorize(http)
service = build("plus", "v1", http=http)
o = service.people().get(userId='me').execute()
```

The same is also true when I use the Google+ explorer:

http://code.google.com/apis/explorer/#_s=plus&_v=v1&_m=people.get&fields=emails

If I switch to private with the user who created the API, then I can fetch 'me', but if I authorize another user, then I can't fetch 'me'.

Any ideas what is happening?

Comment: Show where you define `gp_client`

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured out what this was. Google lets you authorize any google account for an app. However, if the authorizing user hasn't upgraded to Google+, when the app makes its first Google+ API request, the request will 404. This is mind boggling, because when I setup the OAuth2WebServerFlow I specified "plus.me" as the scope... IMHO Google should tell the user to upgrade to Google+ when they try to authorize this OAuth request.

```
gp_client = OAuth2WebServerFlow(
    settings.GOOGLE_PLUS_CONSUMER_ID,
    settings.GOOGLE_PLUS_CONSUMER_SECRET,
    scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me',
)
```